# Proving that a set is isolated in $C_X$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $A\subset X$ be a finite set of isolated points in $X$. Then I want to prove that $A$ is isolated in $(\mathcal C_X,d_H)$ where

$$C_X=\{\text{non empty compact subsets of X}\}$$ ,

$$d_H(A, B) = \inf\{ \epsilon > 0: A \subset U_{\epsilon}(B),\ \ B\subset U_\epsilon(A)\}.$$

and

$$U_{\epsilon}(A)=\{x\in X: d(x,A)<\epsilon\}$$

So what I did is that I argued that since $A$ is finite and isolated, then it is compact, so $A\subset \mathcal C_X$, but I am not sure about this argument, so, Can someone tell me if I am right? or how to fix my proof please?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If each point of $A = \{x_1,\ldots,x_n\}$ is an isolated point of $X$, then  for each $x_k \in A$ there exists a ball $B(x_k,\epsilon_k)$ with the property that $X \cap B(x_k,\epsilon_k) = \{x_k\}$. Let $\epsilon = \min\{\epsilon_1,\ldots,\epsilon_n\}$. You can verify without too much hassle that $$U_\epsilon(A) = A.$$

If $B \subset U_\epsilon(A)$ then $B \subset A$.  It follows that if $A \subset U_\epsilon (B)$ you must have $B = A$ since the points of $A$ are at least $\epsilon$ apart from each other.

Thus $d_H(A,B) \le \epsilon$ implies $A = B$. $A$ is isolated in $C_X$.

Comment: Right, but what do you mean by to much hassle?

Comment: I mean it is simple to show.

Comment: aaaa ok, let me check, and if I have further questions can I let you know?